# nextui table shrinks when adding onLoadMore

Tags: css, reactjs, nextui

[image: here before onLoadMore]

[image: after]

when I add the onLoadMore function to the table it shrinks have no clue how to fix it
using nextui

```
 <Table
      aria-label="Example table with custom cells"
      css={{
        height: "30vh",
        minWidth: "100%",
      }}

      selectionMode="multiple"
    >
      <Table.Header columns={columns}>
        {(column) => (
          <Table.Column
            key={column.uid}
            hideHeader={column.uid === "actions"}
            align={column.uid === "actions" ? "center" : "start"}
          >
            {column.name}
          </Table.Column>
        )}
      </Table.Header>
      <Table.Body loadingState={"f"}
        onLoadMore={()=>console.log("hhh")} items={users}>
        {(item) => (
          <Table.Row>
            {(columnKey) => (
              <Table.Cell>{renderCell(item, columnKey)}</Table.Cell>
            )}
          </Table.Row>
        )}
      </Table.Body>
    </Table>
  );
```

when I add the onLoadMore function to the table it shrinks have no clue how to fix it
using nextui

when I add the onLoadMore function to the table it shrinks have no clue how to fix it
using nextui

when I add the onLoadMore function to the table it shrinks have no clue how to fix it
using nextui